# Quantity with approximate lognormal distribution

Tags: statistics

I am studying a quantity $x$ for which $\log( x)$ is nearly (although not exactly) lognormal. What would be the appropriate "typical" value: the mean $\langle x\rangle$ or rather $e^{\langle\log(x)\rangle}$?

Comment: Would http://stats.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: You mean, $\log(x)$ is normal, not lognormal, right? Then the both means are same: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogNormalDistribution.html. But yeah, this does not belong here at all.